# Parsing CSV and then count the occurrence by date?

Tags: powershell

I need to parse a CSV file like in the attached image, and then generate the summary report based on the frequency of the specific keywords in the message_subject column like '*Auto Reply:*'

Source Input.CSV: https://pastebin.com/3iaUMCPd

[image]

The expected result is:

```
Sender_Address,        Frequency, Date (Ascending sorted)
Inspector1@domain.net, 3,         2022-09-27, 2022-09-28
Inspector2@domain.net, 2,         2022-10-04, 2022-09-30
Inspector3@domain.net, 1,         2022-10-06
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the output should be 1) grouped and sorted by `sender_address` 2) the Date column should only have the date part (no time) and be a uniqified comma (or otherwise) separated list

Comment: what are the keywords? the strings in message_subject or a substring of those?

Comment: @Toni, the keyword is "Auto Reply:*" so anything else can be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Group-Object` to group the rows by sender address, then use `Sort-Object -Unique` to grab all unique dates:

```
Import-Csv path\to\file.csv |Group-Object sender_address |ForEach-Object {
  # Parse timestamps, grab unique dates
  $uniqueDates = $_.Group |ForEach-Object { [datetime]::Parse($_.origin_timestamp_utc).Date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') } |Sort-Object -Unique

  # Create a new object to hold the frequency info
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Sender_address = $_.Name
    Frequency = $_.Count
    Dates = $uniqueDates -join ', '
  }
} |Export-Csv path\to\result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, by using `group-object` to group by Sender_Address and then using `Select-object` with calculated properties to count the keyWord 'Auto Reply' and gather the related dates (sorted):

```
#Load csv
$csv = import-csv [path]

#Calculate output
$csv | Group-Object -Property 'sender_address' | Select-Object Name,@{name='keyWordCount';expression={($_.group.'message_subject' -match 'Auto Reply').count}},@{name='origin_timestamp_utc';expression={(($_.group | ?{$_.'message_subject' -match 'Auto Reply'}).'origin_timestamp_utc' | Sort-Object) -join ","}}

#Output
Name                  keyWordCount origin_timestamp_utc
----                  ------------ --------------------
Inspector1@DOMAIN.net            3 2022-09-27T19:38:02.2054022Z,2022-09-28T19:38:03.0335704Z,2022-09-28T19:38:03.06298…
Inspector2@DOMAIN.net            2 2022-09-30T19:38:02.8562799Z,2022-10-04T02:33:07.6877938Z
Inspector3@DOMAIN.net            1 2022-10-06T23:30:12.3284393Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on the problem:

```sh
# Create sample data
$csv = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
origin_timestamp_utc,sender_address,message_subject,directionality,connector_id,delivery_priority
2022-09-27T19:38:02.1826859Z,Inspector1@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20220927,Originating,,Normal
2022-09-27T19:38:02.2054022Z,Inspector1@domain.net,Auto Reply: Vehicle Reports are due now.,Originating,,Normal
2022-09-28T19:38:03.0335704Z,Inspector1@domain.net,Auto Reply: Late in the office.,Originating,,Normal
2022-09-28T19:38:03.0629852Z,Inspector1@domain.net,Auto Reply: Sick not well :-(,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-05T19:38:02.1819402Z,Inspector1@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20221005,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-05T19:38:02.1903258Z,Inspector1@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20221005,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-06T19:38:02.2743619Z,Inspector1@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20221006,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-06T19:38:02.2821327Z,Inspector1@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20221006,Originating,,Normal
2022-09-29T19:38:02.1361255Z,Inspector2@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20220929,Originating,,Normal
2022-09-29T19:38:02.1453714Z,Inspector2@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20220929,Originating,,Normal
2022-09-30T19:38:02.8562799Z,Inspector2@domain.net,Auto Reply: Out of office today?!??!,Originating,,Normal
2022-09-30T19:38:02.8979890Z,Inspector2@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20220930,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-03T19:38:02.5937670Z,Inspector2@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20221003,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-04T02:33:07.6877938Z,Inspector2@domain.net,Auto Reply: Not in the Office ?,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-04T19:38:02.6117533Z,Inspector2@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20221004,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-01T19:38:03.3718620Z,Inspector3@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20221001,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-01T19:38:04.8114745Z,Inspector3@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20221001,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-02T19:38:02.2517865Z,Inspector3@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20221002,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-02T19:38:02.2855767Z,Inspector3@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20221002,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-03T19:38:02.5937670Z,Inspector3@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20221003,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-04T19:38:02.6383853Z,Inspector3@domain.net,Customer Vehicle Conditions report for 20221004,Originating,,Normal
2022-10-06T23:30:12.3284393Z,Inspector3@domain.net,Auto Reply: Where are you !!!!,Originating,,Normal
'@

$keyWord = 'Auto Reply:*'

$csv | Group-Object sender_address | ForEach-Object {

    # From current group, get all date/times where the message_subject matches the keyword
    $dates = $_.Group.Where{ $_.message_subject -like $keyWord }.ForEach{ $_.origin_timestamp_utc }

    # Remove the time part and get unique dates
    $uniqueDates = $dates -replace 'T.+' | Sort-Object -Unique

    # Output
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Sender_Address = $_.Name
        Frequency = $dates.Count
        'Date (Ascending sorted)' = $uniqueDates -join ', '
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```text
Sender_Address        Frequency Date (Ascending sorted)
--------------        --------- -----------------------
Inspector1@domain.net         3 2022-09-27, 2022-09-28 
Inspector2@domain.net         2 2022-09-30, 2022-10-04 
Inspector3@domain.net         1 2022-10-06
```

Compared to the expected output, there is a slight difference in the `Date` column, 2nd row. I have interpreted the "ascending sorted" to be applied to each row individually. I'm not sure if OP actually meant to sort the whole column (possibly by newest date).

Answer (score 1):

This solves your problem, including ascending sorting for the dates:

```
# gets all messages starting with "Auto Reply"
$messages = Import-Csv <your file> | Where-Object message_subject -match "Auto Reply.*"  
# changes timestamp format to date only
$messages | ForEach-Object { $_.origin_timestamp_utc = [datetime]::Parse($_.origin_timestamp_utc).Date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') } 
#groups by sender_adress
$messages | Group-Object sender_address | ForEach-Object {
    $sortedDates = ""
    # sorts dates so the date with the least amount of messages comes first (you can change this with Sort-Object -descending)
    $_.group | Group-Object origin_timestamp_utc | Sort-Object count | ForEach-Object {
        $sortedDates += $_.Name + ","
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
      Sender_Address = $_.Name
      Frequency = $_.Count
      "Date (Ascending Sorted)" = $sortedDates.TrimEnd(",") #remove last ","
    }
}
```

Add `Export-Csv` to export it

Comment: Thanks, @X.Yap for your contribution